# Swap cases in string if word begins with uppercase

Tags: python, python-3.x

i need to take a input sentence like

input: `Hello world its Monday.`

output: `hELLO world its mONDAY.`

I basically need to swap cases if the word starts with uppercase. I know how to swap cases, but the .isupper() always returns false.

```
x = str(input("Enter your sentence please. "))

y = x.split(" ")

print(y)

######THIS OUTPUTS FALSE NO MATTER WHAT
for i in range(0,len(y)):
  if y[i].isupper() == True:
    print("True")
  else:
    print("False")
```

Comment: In `y[i]` you have a full word, and `isupper()` checks if all of it is upper-case. If you want to check just the first letter of each word, do: `y[i][0]`

Comment: you are checking the whole word is upper or not. `"Hello".isupper() return false` isupper returns True if only all characters are upper. In this case you need to iterate each letter to see if it is upper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use indexing to check if first character is uppercase or not:

```
a = "Hello world its Monday"

x = [i.swapcase() if i[0].isupper() else i for i in a.split()]

print(" ".join(x))
```

Output:

```
hELLO world its mONDAY
```

Answer (score 1):

isupper() returns True if all the characters in a word are uppercase. You can solve your problem just by checking the first char of each word.

```
 s = "This is a sentence".split()
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i][0].isupper():
         print(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you iterate over `y` which is a list of strings

```
Enter your sentence please. test TEST
['test', 'TEST']
```

In order to do what you want, you can join this list and iterate over string

```
y = ''.join(x.split(" "))  # This is a string
print(y)  # prints 'testTEST'

for i in y:
  if i.isupper() == True:
...
```